# Infinite sets: $|a| < |b|$ implies $|c^a| < |c^b|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $a,b,c$ are infinite sets, is it true that $|a| < |b|$ implies $|c^a| < |c^b|$?

Obviously $|a| < |b|$ implies $|c^a| \leq |c^b|$, but I want to show $c^a$ does not biject with $c^b$...

Comment: I am pretty sure this was asked and answered a million times by now on this site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please find the relevant links and vote to close this question, thanks

Answer (score 3):

No. If $|a|=\aleph_0 $, $|b|=\mathfrak{c}$ and $|c|=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ then $|c^a| =2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ and $|c^b| =2^{\mathfrak{c}}$  (here $\mathfrak{c}$ is the size of the continuum, i.e. the cardinality of the real numbers = $2^{\aleph_0}$).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Is it because $|c^a| = |c^b| = |c|$ whenever $|a| < |b| < |c|$? If it's true can you please give a sketch proof? (Or point me to somewhere where a sketch proof may be found.) Thanks